# Тупит github. Команды плохо работают

Tags: git

Есть аккаунт на гитхабе. Подключение через ssh.
Но любое действие связанное с подключением к репозиториям ужасно тормозит и тупит.

git clone, pull и push работают по 15-30c, после чего говорят мне что репозитория нет или у меня нет прав.

Это происходит 19 раз из 20.

На 20-ый раз таки команды срабатывают.

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: В связи или состоянии днс, возможны неверные настройки

Comment: Гитхаб — не человек, он не может тупить. Проверяйте связь до гитхаба.

Comment: @NickVolynkin но GitHub писали люди, так что может xD